# How to change Ubuntu logo (start-here)?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome

In Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty), I cannot find the way to change Ubuntu logo (start-here) on Gnome panel.

I cannot do right-click on panel to change something, for example moving some indicator, changing background of Gnome panel.

Anyone know how to, please share it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The Panel in `11.04` is a part of the new Ubuntu Interface [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/).

**Now about moving indicators and right-click to add applets like previous versions of Ubuntu, this is not possible.**

The only possible thing is to add more Indicators to the panel :
[List of Application indicators](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators)

And there is a way to change the Opacity of the panel, by using `ccsm`: [Click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

This can be done by going to **Desktop** --> **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** --> **Experimental**

[image]

**And for the Ubuntu Logo: This can be done by changing the theme or just the icons:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quickly answer. Really it's not good that we can't change or customize something in Ubuntu. Because the fascinating things in Linux that it has much things to change into ours favorite.I hope we can find the way to change day by day on using Natty.
About moving the order of indicators in Natty: see the link 
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/how-to-change-application-indicators.html

Comment: @thong trang: I couldn't agree with you more.And for the moving indicators; this is a workaround, for this reason I didn't mention it in the answer.You can find many things like this from scripts to configuration files.But I believe this will be easily done in 11.10. And if the answer suits you please click the green button above:).Also if u need anything else I'm ready to help.

Comment: They're deliberately not adding customization options while the interface itself is still under heavy development, I would assume.

Answer (score 0):

To change Ubuntu Logo - Start Here you wil need Ubuntu Tweak.

[image]

Go to Gnome Settings and there is a button to change it to whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Thx Wojciech so much. I succeeded to apply it.